# Postman is not responding and hashedPassword is not generated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, postman

I am simply trying to create a hashedpassword using bcryptjs and console.log that password so that I can copy and use it

i am using postman to test my POST request my plan is to send the request body as(email, password) using postman and i will read the body and pass the password to bcryptjs which will generate a hashedpassword and i want to console.log that out

**now hashedpassword is not generated and also postman is not responding please help**

index.js:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const exppess=require('express')
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser')
const cors=require('cors')
const { verify }=require('jsonwebtoken')
const { hash, compare } = require('bcryptjs');
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { DB } = require('./DB');

const server=exppess()
server.use(cookieParser )


server.use(exppess.json )
server.use(exppess.urlencoded({ extended: true }))


server.post("/register",async (req,res)=>{
  const { email, password } = req.body
  try{
    const hashedPassword = await hash(password, 10)
    console.log(hashedPassword)
  }
  catch(err){
    res.send({
      error: `${err.message}`,
    })
  }
})

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log('server started on port: '+process.env.PORT);
 });
```

.env file

```html
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=weibenrules
REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET=weibenrulesevenmore
PORT=4000
```

Terminal:screenshot
[image]

Postman:
in the body i am setting email and password as key value pair
[image]

Comment: You are not sending a reply if the hashing succeeds, only when it fails... You should see the output of `console.log(hashedPassword)` in your terminal though.

Comment: can you please explain or a demo

Comment: In your /register handler, you need to call `res.send("success");` or whatever. You are not sending a response currently (only in the case of an error), so the postman requests will simply time out.

Comment: You should also remove `server.use(exppess.json )` or fix it: `server.use(exppess.json())` (and probably rename exppess to express)

Comment: yes i did what you just told me but not working

Comment: Can you edit your question with the changes you've made? Also, do you see the console.log output in the console?

Answer (score 0):

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const exppess=require('express')
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser')
const cors=require('cors')
const { verify }=require('jsonwebtoken')
const { hash, compare } = require('bcryptjs');
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { DB } = require('./DB');

const server=exppess()
server.use(cookieParser )


server.use(exppess.json )
server.use(exppess.urlencoded({ extended: true }))


server.post("/register",async (req,res)=>{
  const { email, password } = req.body
  try{
    const hashedPassword = await hash(password, 10)
    console.log(hashedPassword)
    res.send(hashedPassword)
  }
  catch(err){
    res.send({
      error: `${err.message}`,
    })
  }
})

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log('server started on port: '+process.env.PORT);
 });
```